# pg_basebackup error: old directory is not an absolute path in tablespace mapping

Tags: postgresql, database-administration

I'm trying to take backup using pg_basebackup on Linux from PostgreSQL remote server running on Windows.
I'm getting error as follows.

```
$ ./pg_basebackup -D backup/remote2 -X stream 
--tablespace-mapping="C:\Users\***\postgres\pgbuild\bin\temp\tablespace01"=/home/***/postgres/build/bin/backup/tbs/tbs01 
-h ***.***.***.*** -p 5432 -U username
pg_basebackup: error: old directory is not an absolute path in tablespace mapping: C:\Users\***\postgres\pgbuild\bin\temp\tablespace01
```

I couldn't find any example on internet where backup is performed across platforms (windows to linux). Is it even allowed with pg_basebackup?

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in the PostgreSQL, now it is fixed, read [this](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CA+TgmoY+jC3YiskomvYKDPK3FbrmsDU7_8+wMHt02HOdJeRb0g@mail.gmail.com) for more detail